# "no" + verb + "nada"

Tags: gramática, adverbios

## Español

¿Por qué "say nothing" en inglés se traduce como "no habla nada" en español? 
¿Por qué hay una extra "no"? Otro ejemplo: "I know nothing" en inglés se traduce "Yo no sé nada" en español.

---

## Inglés

Why is it that to say "say nothing" in Spanish, one would write "no habla de nada"? Why the extra "no"? Another example: "I know nothing" translates to "Yo no sé nada".

Comment: ¿Dónde has visto "no habla de nada"? La traducción de "say nothing" sería "no digas nada". ¿Cuál es el contexto?

Comment: @JoulSauron: Lo vi en un vídeo de Youtube :)

Comment: As @JoulSauron says, while "no habla de nada" is valid Spanish, it's not a valid translation for "say nothing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En español no existe la doble negación, es decir, se pueden añadir más adverbios de negación sin que la oración pase a ser afirmativa, solo refuerza que sea negativa:

Según [esta nota de](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#ap8) la RAE:

> En español existe un esquema particular de negación, que permite combinar el adverbio *no* con la presencia de otros elementos que tienen también sentido negativo.
>
> Los adverbios *nunca, jamás, tampoco*, los indefinidos *nadie, nada, ninguno*, la locución *en la/mi/tu/su vida* y los grupos que contienen la palabra *ni* aparecen siempre en oraciones de sentido negativo. Si estos elementos van antepuestos al verbo, este no va acompañado del adverbio de negación *no*: *Nunca voy al teatro; Él tampoco está de acuerdo*.
>   Pero si van pospuestos al verbo, este debe ir necesariamente precedido del adverbio *no*: *No voy nunca al teatro*; *Él no está de acuerdo tampoco*.
>
> La concurrencia de esas dos «negaciones» no anula el sentido negativo del enunciado, sino que lo refuerza.

Comment: So these mean the same thing: "nunca como pescado" and "no como nunca pescado".  But the second is more emphatic?

Comment: @Steve D I would say that "nunca como pescado" and "no como nunca pescado" are exactly the same in meaning and emphasis, but "nunca como pescado" is more concise and better style.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JoulSauron's answer, but in a simple way: "nada" can be translated "nothing" or as "anything", depending on the context. A couple of examples:

¿Qué quieres? Nada = What do you want? Nothing

¿Qué quieres? No quiero nada = What do you want? I don't want anything ( = I want nothing )

In Spanish, you if you use "nada" and a verb, the "no" must be there, too. You cannot say "Quiero nada". As the sentences is negative, the "no" is mandatory. It's just idiomatic, something that must be learnt that way, but you can think that the english "nothing" is stronger than the spanish "nada".

Comment: Both you and @JoulSauron really helped me: I kept thinking in terms of double negatives, but I see now it is not the same thing in Spanish. Thanks!

Comment: You can perfectly say "nada quiero".

Comment: "Nada quiero" would not be used in a normal conversation. It is usual in songs in poems, but not in informal Spanish.

Comment: @Nacho If you don't like "nada quiero", just change the verb. This sentences would be use in normal conversation: "Nada me gustaría más que ganar esta carrera. Nada sabemos del origen de estas radiaciones. Nada conseguirás con tu actitud. Nada podemos contra los designios de Dios."

Comment: @Albertus I disagree. All those sentences are perfectly correct, but not "usable in normal conversation". They are all a bit too poetic for that.